# VIsual Studio 2019 Entity Data Model Wizard AssemblyFile is null

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

I've created a WebSite Project in Visual Studio 2019, but when I try to add an ADO Entity Model and I click on New COnnection, Visual Studio raise an error:

> assemblyFile is null or empty
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ExecutorWrapper...

[image]

After clicking on Abort, the only button that can close the error window, VS crashes.
I've tried to reinstall everything from scratch several times, I've installed also on another PC but the error persists.

The reference to the assembly System.Data.Entity is in the webconfig:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Anyone knows how to solve or Database first in EF6 must be forget??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen to me on a website project. I change it to use Web Application project and now EF works fine. Try that.